# Remove all nodes after a specified node

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I'm grabbing a div of text from a url and would like to remove everything underneath a paragraph which has a `backtotop` class. I'd seen a traverse snippet of code here on stackoverflow which looks promising, but I can't figure out how to get it incorporated so @el only contains everything up to the first `p.backtotop` in the div.

my code:

```
@doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
@el = @doc.css("div")[0]
end
```

traverse snippet:

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(code)
stop_node = doc.css("p.backtotop")
doc.traverse do |node|
break if node == stop_node
# else, do whatever, e.g. `puts node.name`
end
```

Answer (score 4):

1. Find the div you want.
2. Find the 'stop' item you want, and then find all the following siblings.
3. Remove them.

For example:

```html
<body>
  <div id="a">
    <h2>My Section</h2>
    <p class="backtotop">Back to Top</p>
    <p>More Content</p>
    <p>Even More Content</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

```ruby
require 'nokogiri'
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(my_html)
div = doc.at('#a')
div.at('.backtotop').xpath('following-sibling::*').remove
puts div
#=> <div id="a">
#=>     <h2>My Section</h2>
#=>     <p class="backtotop">Back to Top</p>
#=>     
#=>     
#=>   </div>
```

Here's a more complicated example, where the `backtotop` item may not be at the root of the div:

```html
<body>
  <div id="b">
    <h2>Another Section</h2>
    <section>
      <p class="backtotop">Back to Top</p>
      <p>More Content</p>
     </section>
    <p>Even More Content</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

```ruby
require 'nokogiri'
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(my_html)
div = doc.at('#b')
n   = div.at('.backtotop')
until n==div
  n.xpath('following-sibling::*').remove
  n = n.parent
end

puts div
#=> <div id="b">
#=>     <h2>Another Section</h2>
#=>     <section><p class="backtotop">Back to Top</p>
#=>       
#=>      </section>
#=>   </div>
```

If your HTML is more complicated than the above then please provide an actual sample along with the result you want. *This is good advice for any future question you ask.*

Comment: how to compact the result? (remove empty lines)

Comment: This is great answer! Thanks